# why we use description attribute for class property in c#

Tags: c#, attributes, field-description

i saw in some code that use Description attribute for class property and i couldn't find reason of behavior in c# codding

```
 public class sample
    {
        [Description("description1")]
        public string PropertyOnne{ get; set; }

     }
```

for readability of code we can use xml summary for even property and i didn't understand what is difference between summary and Description attribute in class level.

Comment: You can use those e.g. for the descriptions displayed in the visual designer (WinForms) or in any other UI (WPF app).

Comment: what do you mean by `summary`?

Comment: @JohnB xml summary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary

Comment: so you are comparing comments (not-compiled) to an attribute (compiled)?  please do some basic background reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple words, you can consider below explanation

- The  tag is used to generate documentation in XML for your Project at Compile time, this is also used by the visual studio for its intellisense database
- The Description attribute used by the designer in order to understand the text, mostly at the bottom of the property window(for reference).

Answer (score 2):

This is for visual designers, they can display the description when referencing them.

Remark from the docs:

> A visual designer can display the specified description when referencing the component member, such as in a Properties window. Call Description to access the value of this attribute.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2